# Why are most my objects not visible in new windows and when its rendered out?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

[image: Stadium]

When I open new windows or render out images, it looks like whats on the right. The window on the left is the original window I've been working on to make this thing. This project is due in 2 days and I need this figured out as fast as I can.

Comment: Are your objects in different layers?

Comment: Note that you are in local view. Try pressing numpad / while hovering over the view on the left

Comment: I dont think they are in different layers, but i dont even see the layers option in the left window.

Comment: and as for the numpad solution, i pressed every number on the numpad on the left side and it all said local

Comment: @cegaton forgot to tag

Comment: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/Global_or_Local_View

Comment: that has to be it @cegaton, I was trying to figure out where his layers had gone.

Comment: @BlendingJake layers are hidden while in local view

Comment: @Noobie337 Try this: press Space-bar, then type "Local View", then press Enter. This will take you out of local view. The way you can tell you are in local view is the text on the upper-left side of the viewport(which in you image says: "User Ortho(Local)").